# Samsung S7 - Facebook Messenger Drains A Lot of Data

Tags: 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, facebook-messenger

I have the fb messenger app on my phone which I use regularly, but in all the months I've used my phone, I've never surpassed 50 MB per month of data usage for that app.

About 2 weeks ago, I got the Nougat 7 update, and I believe ever since then (it started happening around the same time) my Messenger app has been draining data. Within a week, it used about 500 MB of background data.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's very bizzare that messenger using heavy data.

The possibilities are:

• May be you have shared a video to few contacts and it is using data!

• May be you have clicked a big video file and switch to another app(video is still loading and using data to finish it to the end of video).
Or
• Viewing videos frequently shared by someone.

If these things are excluded, it may be a bug.

• See playstore if there is an update.

Or try clearing Cache and Data and log in again then observe data usage.